# How do I expand all strings in a .resx resource file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: resources, visual-studio-2012, designer

VS2012's resource designer doesn't seem to have a way to "expand" long strings of text/html.

I have to double-click each and every one line to expand it.

Knowing I have about 10,000 of these to do for this localization project, I'm going to go mad if I can't find a way to go from this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1F5.jpg

...to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2pU7.jpg

If there isn't, please suggest some alternate tool, app, or method that will help me keep my sanity.

Comment: This would be better served on SO as it deals with programming tools/implementations and not conceptual/design concepts. Please don't re-ask this there as it can be migrated. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs on SO. If it has you in front of a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers.

Comment: Simply use copy + paste to use your favorite html editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Visual Studio Power Productivity Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) for some help there. I know they really enhanced it for opening and collapsing the solution folders so it might help you.

At our company we wrote a small utility to extract these resources from Visual Studio to package in the excel format that our translation company uses. It didn't take much to do that in .NET and it will certainly make your life easier in the long run.

Turns out Microsoft also has a [Resource Refactoring Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae29d3-81e1-43d4-9c48-fc9644869d84) that looks like it makes it easy to pull resources out of the code and resx files into other formats. I have not tried this personally (where I have used the Productivity Tools) but it is worth looking into this option.

Comment: Thanks, Akira. I'll have a look at VSPPT and the refactoring tool. Am really surprised a basic feature like this isn't already part of the designer, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: Sometimes in the rush to get software out we all forget simple things or have to set them aside. This is why Microsoft often releases these types of productivity packs. There are a lot of community submitted and official ones out there. Good luck with your endeavors.